# Separating numbers in an input in C

Tags: c, input

I need to take a 4 digit input from stdin in C such as 1234, and store the numbers separately like 1, 2, 3, 4. How could I do this?

Comment: Define "input".  From the command line?  From stdin?  From an int?  From a char[]?

Comment: Is this input stored as e.g. an `int`, or as a string (an array of `char`)?

Comment: stdin. tried using an array of char but it just stored the whole number in the first location and the rest as 0's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read it as a string (`char*`). Pseudocode

```
char str[MaxLen];
Input str;
possibly do some checking that the input string is in required format.
int a0 = str[0] - '0';
int a1 = str[1] - '0';
etc.
```

Comment: Are you sure that's portable?

Comment: That's not working, just gives the 4 digit number as str[0]

Comment: @someguy: What's not portable about it?

Comment: @KieranMilton: Yes, it is working, it's just that you must be doing something wrong. Edit your question with your ACTUAL code and I will point to your mistake

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: You're under the assumption that '1' follows '0', '2' follows '1' etc.

Comment: I do apologise, another bit of my code blocked it, works great thanks!

Comment: @someguy: That is ***practically*** portable. You cannot point me to any encoding where that is not the case. However, if you want to be so painful about it, you can always write a 10-case switch.

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: Or you could convert it to an integer using one of the standard library functions, which do all the platform-dependant work for you. One of the other answers shows this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
int no, i=0, a[4];
scanf("%d", &no);
while(i<4)
{
  a[i]=no%10;
  no /= 10;
  i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use getchar:

```
int a[4],c,i;
for (i=0;i<4;i++) {
 while (!isdigit(c=getchar()));
 a[i]=c-'0';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
void separate_digits(int four_digits, int *outarray)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        outarray[i] = four_digits % 10;
        four_digits = four_digits / 10;
    }
}
```

Make sure outarray is big enough!

Comment: Oh, just noticed that by input you mean from stdin... Slightly less useful then.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code:

```
char input[100];
// we know that every digit is less than 10, so a full int isn't necessary
int8_t output[100];

// set all values to -1
memset(output, -1, sizeof(output));

scanf("%99s", &input);

int len = (int) strlen(input);

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    // assuming input is in ASCII
    output[i] = input[i] - '0';
}

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    if (output[i] == -1)
    {
        break;
    }

    printf("%i, ", output[i]);
}
```

This takes an input of up to 100 characters, and outputs the individual digits of each.

Comment: -1 for buffer overflow due to unsafe use of scanf.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Uhm, what? unless the user inputs over 100 characters, I don't see whats wrong...

Comment: The OP Clearly states that it was intended for 4 characters, this just extended that functionality a little bit.

Comment: Yup.  And it's this kind of thinking that has resulted in security issue after security issue for decades.  The sad reality is that people copy-paste whatever code is out there, so we should not needlessly write vulnerable code.  `gets()` has been officially deprecated in C; `scanf()` is no better.

Comment: Change your `scanf` to `scanf("%99s", &input);` and you should be ok.

Comment: Thanks @Wes, I don't use scanf much, and you helped me out a bit :)